# How to replace an undefined value returned? (RequestJS)

Tags: javascript, undefined, requestjs

I'm creating a bot for Discord and trying to do some things with the NASA API. However, there's no copyright for every single image, so I'd like that when it happens, it replace "undefined" by something else. Would it be possible to do that?

Here's my code:

```
    "nasapic": {
        name: "nasapic",
        help: "Utilisez cette commande pour afficher l'image du jour sur http:///apod.nasa.gov/",
        process: function (bot, msg, suffix) {
          request("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date="+suffix+"&hd=True&api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo", function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                var nasaPic = JSON.parse(body);
                var msgArray = [];
                msgArray.push("Photographie du " + nasaPic.date + " prise par " + nasaPic.copyright + "\n");
                msgArray.push("Titre : **" + nasaPic.title + "**\n");
                console.log(msg.author.name + " " + "a utilisé la commande /nasapic");
                msgArray.push(nasaPic.url);
                if (nasaPic.code == 400) {
                  bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, ":x: Une erreur est survenue. Rappel de la syntaxe : **YYYY-MM-DD**"); }
                if (nasaPic.copyright == undefined) {
                  nasaPic.copyright.replace("undefined", "test");
                  bot.sendMessage(msg, msgArray); }
                else bot.sendMessage(msg, msgArray);
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Here are the two lines that are problematic:

```
if (nasaPic.copyright == undefined) {
                  nasaPic.copyright.replace("undefined", "test");
                  bot.sendMessage(msg, msgArray); }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are looking for

```
if (typeof(nasaPic.copyright) == 'undefined') {
    nasaPic.copyright = 'test';
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. However, when I use this, I got a SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Here's the pastebin of the error and intent log: http://pastebin.com/CA0Sxrv8

Comment: It is working for me with "nasaPic" - data, please see https://jsfiddle.net/sts8djos/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is this:

```
if (!nasaPic.copyright) {
    nasaPic.copyright = "default copyright";
}
```

The only problem is a null, undefined, or empty value will go to this method.  I think that is preferred in this situation.  Otherwise you'll need to use typeof.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. However, when I use this, I got a SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Here's the pastebin of the error and intent log: http://pastebin.com/CA0Sxrv8

Comment: Is this from when you parse the body?

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a bad response from the nasa server although it isn't a 400 or a 500 error, the body isn't Json.  Easiest way to get around this would without more investigation is to add a try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

`nasaPic.copyright.replace("undefined", "test");`

Will not work for you, since `nasaPic.copyright` is undefined. Since it is undefined, it will not have a `.replace` function available. Instead, do the following:

```
if (!nasaPic.copyright) {
      nasaPic.copyright = "test";
      ...
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. However, when I use this, I got a SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Here's the pastebin of the error and intent log: http://pastebin.com/CA0Sxrv8